# Emitting a list in a signal

Tags: python-3.x, pyside, signals-slots, qlistwidget

I'm trying to create a version of QListWidget (in PySide) in which the itemClicked signal will carry not one item, but a list of all items in the QListWidget.

I tried different things, but no luck so far. This is what I have ATM:

```
class RelationsListWidget(QListWidget):
    all_items = Signal(list)
    item_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        QListWidget.__init__(self)
        self.itemClicked.connect(self.gather_items)

    def gather_items(self):
        self.item_list = [self.item(i) for i in range(self.count())]
        self.all_items.emit(self.item_list)
```

but when I connect it:

```
class NodeEditWindow(QDialog):
   ...
   self.list_consumes = RelationsListWidget()
   self.list_consumes.itemClicked.connect(self.create_SelectRelationsWindow)
   ...
   @Slot(object)
   def create_SelectRelationsWindow(self, list_widget):
       print("create_SelectRelationsWindow: %s" % type(list_widget))
```

I'm getting:

```
create_SelectRelationsWindow: <class '__main__.NodeItem'>
```

so it carries only one item, not a list.

---

related questions:

[How to connect custom signal to slot in pyside with the new syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874211/how-to-connect-custom-signal-to-slot-in-pyside-with-the-new-syntax)

[PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtSignal object has no attribute 'connect'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970312/pyqt4-qtcore-pyqtsignal-object-has-no-attribute-connect)

Comment: What is the point of sending a list of all the items? Why not just send a reference to the list-widget itself? Or maybe you don't even need to do that, if the receiver already has a reference.

Comment: Sending a reference is fine, but I don't know how to do it either. The receiver doesn't have a reference, at least AFAIK (I'm new to PySide).

Can the signal receiving object tell where did the signal came from?

Comment: A "reference" just means any variable that points to the object. In your example code, the receiver clearly *does* have a reference to the list-widget - i.e. `self.list_consumes`. So there's no need to send anything in the signal - just pull the items directly from the list-widget.

Comment: damn, you're right, of course the `NodeEditWindow` widget does have a reference. There is a problem, though: there will be a few other lists apart from the `self.list_consumes` connected to that slot.  How will the Slot method know which list did it get the signal from? (items are not unique, the same item can be on multiple lists).

Comment: You can use `self.sender()` in the slot.

Comment: thanks a lot! that solves the problem